# SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2501, context 3:0:0

Tags: oracle, unix, stored-procedures

Getting Enter value for attrname: SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2501, context 3:0:0  error when running a procedure .Unsafe to proceed.

When invoking the procedure, i am invoking the procedure as below in the unix script :
Procedurename('&attrName');

This procedure was working and suddenly stopped working. Can anyone suggest what is the alternative to pass the attrName.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if I run `startup nomount` then  `conn / as sysdba`, will got this error.

If I run `startup nomount pfile=mypath\pfile.ora` then `conn / as sysdba`, it'll connect success without error.